# Primary key duplicated, however I need to use the values as a foreign later

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

`` INSERT INTO `employee_salary` (`id`, `dep_id`, `employee_hourly`, `employee_annual`) VALUES ('1', '1', '20.00', '40000.00'), ('2', '1', '20.00', '40000.00'), ('3', '2', '30.00', '60000.00'), ('4', '3', '15.00', '30000'), ('5', '3', '15.00', '30000.00'), ('6', '3', '15.00', '30000.00') ``

I keep getting a duplicate primary error, I understand that dep_id is my duplicate as I have multiple people in the same department. I however want to use the dep_id as a foreign key later on when I want to break down the three departments into their department locations and department heads. Do I need to create a different primary, if so I am unsure how I am supposed to show that I have 3 people in the same department and 2 in the other without having the primary key duplicated value-wise?

Comment: `dep_id` doesn't make sense as a primary key in an "employee" table.  Any foreign key reference should be to a *departments* table, not to `employee_salary`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a primary key is to identify a unique identifier for each record in a table. If what you are supplying is not unique, then it is not a primary key..

The beauty of relational databases is that what you 'show' in a Select query is independent of how the data is structured.  You do not need to have to have a primary key AT ALL if you don't wish it and you can still build your report from Employee_Salary as you described it by grouping by department and counting employees.

So think of your primary key as it may help you add, update and delete records, but when it comes to Selecting and summarizing data, it is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I removed the Primary but kept the data, not sure my instructor wants me to have no foreign key in my department table, but it took care of the issue just as you described.